# how to send keystrokes using Jython to a java application

Tags: java, python, keyboard-shortcuts

I am able to use SendKeys module from Python through following code :

```
import os, SendKeys
os.system('program datafile')
SendKeys.SendKeys("""
{PAUSE 0.25}
%{F4}
""")
```

But, SendKeys module is cython not pure python. So, i couldn't use it in Jython.

My requirement is i am automating using Jython library but i could not send keystrokes like (ALT+F4 / CTRL+R / CTRL+SHIFT+I). 
Is there any alternative to SendKeys in Jython ?

Comment: If you only support Jython, [use Java](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/usejava.html)

Comment: Vb script contains SendKeys method but do java contains it ?